# When placing my navigation in the code it turns my whole page into Hyperlinked, Why?

Tags: html, href, nav

I am creating my first website for my coding class and We have to have a title, 3 navigation buttons and a heading and paragrapgh. When I insert the navigation in the code it makes the whole page hyperlinked. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know, the `<nav>` alone can not hyperlink the page. If the whole page is hyperlinked, your closing of `</a>` probably went wrong somewhere in the code.

Comment: Thank you, I will check that out and see if it makes any changes.